Console Application - How to compare values in Excel faster?
I have an excel file and I am trying to find matching values  bases on these criterias.

For ARMADAS B2: D542295890, I am getting the ARMADAW A2:B05KAYIP
I will look for B05KAYIP in the E column ARMADAIWC and get the corresponding D SAPIWC value 0010
Then I look for 0010 in column G SAPW and get the matching value of D542295890 ARMADAS B2.
If B and H matches then I want to color them.


This console application finds the matching values but since there are approx. 400K rows of data for both B and H to match it takes ages to finish. I wonder how I can optimize this code in order to get the matching results like in my code way more faster?
Here is the console app:
using OfficeOpenXml;
using OfficeOpenXml.Style;
using System.Drawing;

string filePath = @"C:\Users\197199\Desktop\SAP-Armada\Test.xlsx";
string logFilePath = @"C:\Users\197199\Desktop\SAP-Armada\matches.txt";

// Ensure the file exists
if (!File.Exists(filePath))
{
    Console.WriteLine("File not found.");
    return;
}
ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;

// Load the Excel file
using var package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(filePath));
// Get the first worksheet in the workbook
var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];

// Define column indices (assuming 1-based index)
int armadasCol = 2; // Replace with actual column index for ARMADAS
int armadawCol = 1; // Replace with actual column index for ARMADAW
int armadaiWCCol = 5; // Replace with actual column index for ARMADAIWC
int sapiWCCol = 4; // Replace with actual column index for SAPIWC
int gCol = 7; // Replace with actual column index for G
int sapsCol = 8; // Replace with actual column index for SAPS

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(logFilePath))
{
    // Read the content of the worksheet and perform the comparison
    for (int row = 2; row <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; row++) // Assuming first row is header
    {
        string armadasValue = worksheet.Cells[row, armadasCol].Text;
        string armadawValue = worksheet.Cells[row, armadawCol].Text;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(armadasValue) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(armadawValue))
        {
            continue; // Skip empty rows
        }

        // Find the corresponding value in ARMADAIWC and SAPIWC
        string sapiWCValue = null;
        for (int i = 2; i <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; i++)
        {
            if (worksheet.Cells[i, armadaiWCCol].Text == armadawValue)
            {
                sapiWCValue = worksheet.Cells[i, sapiWCCol].Text;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sapiWCValue))
        {
            continue; // Skip if no corresponding SAPIWC value is found
        }

        // Find the corresponding value in SAPS
        string sapsValue = null;
        for (int j = 2; j <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; j++)
        {
            if (worksheet.Cells[j, gCol].Text == sapiWCValue)
            {
                if (armadasValue == worksheet.Cells[j, sapsCol].Text)
                {
                    sapsValue = worksheet.Cells[j, sapsCol].Text;

                    // Apply coloring to the matching cells
                    worksheet.Cells[row, armadasCol].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                    worksheet.Cells[row, armadasCol].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Yellow);

                    worksheet.Cells[j, sapsCol].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                    worksheet.Cells[j, sapsCol].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Yellow);

                    string message = $"Match found at row {row}: ARMADA WAREHOUSE = {armadawValue}, ARMADA SERIAL = {armadasValue}, SAP WAREHOUSE = {sapiWCValue}, SAP SERIAL = {sapsValue}{Environment.NewLine}";
                    Console.WriteLine(message);
                    writer.WriteLine(message);

                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sapsValue))
        {
            continue; // Skip if no corresponding SAPS value is found
        }
    }
}

// Save the changes
package.Save();

Console.WriteLine("Comparison and coloring completed.");


Not sure but worksheet.Dimension.End.Row looks like ~1000000. Evidently you do not need to iterate through all rows. In Excel, the End method is used to determine the last occupied cell.

Try to find a way to select the entire worksheet and somehow copy its contents into an array. Then iterate throught the array.

Try building a dictionary, as a one off operation, of the cells that you need to lookup against. Use this for all the comparison operations, but then indexing back to the Excel cell for doing the manipulation. I can have a go at modifying your code if you need an example.

@AndrewB could you please modify my code?
